# Monitor the status of the Internet Swift

Tags: ios, networking, reachability

I know how to check the network connectivity through Reachability.Swift. I want to achieve some thing like, in a view controller, if internet check in the background after the view load, I even know we can start a NSTimer so that it will check lets after 5 minutes and each time call Reachability class to check for the connectivity.

My question is is there any other theory available for this,

I have seen a Library for this 
[Link to Lib](https://github.com/rondinellimorais/HelperLibrary)

However I want to know if someone achieve this neatly in Swift!!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27310465/detecting-network-connectivity-changes-using-reachability-nsnotification-and-ne/34961681#34961681

Comment: Please add this as answer so that I will accept ...

Comment: Hope this helps you.

Comment: @BharatModi..Dont comment it...Please click on "Post your answer" and I will accept and uproot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swift 2.0 - Check Network Using Reachability, NSNotification

```
AppDelegate.swift

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool 
{
      NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector:"checkNetworkStatus", name: ReachabilityChangedNotification, object: nil);

 do{self.reachability = try Reachability.reachabilityForInternetConnection()}catch{}
 do{try self.reachability.startNotifier()}catch{}
 self.checkNetworkStatus()

 return true
}
```

Declare networkStatus variable

```
var networkStatus : Reachability.NetworkStatus!
checkNetworkStatus() Function

func checkNetworkStatus()
{
  networkStatus = reachability.currentReachabilityStatus

  if (networkStatus == Reachability.NetworkStatus.NotReachable)
  {
    print("Not Reachable")
  }
  else
 {
    print("Reachable")
 }
 }
```

OtherClass.Swift

```
let delegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as!  AppDelegate

 if (delegate.networkStatus!=Reachability.NetworkStatus.NotReachable)
 {
    // Call Webservice     
 }
 else
 {
    delegate.checkNetworkStatus()  //Not Reachable print  
 }
```

Comment: Thanks !!! Man..You saved my day at last!!!

Comment: can you post the code for Reachability?

Comment: Here is the link to the Reachability on GitHub https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift/blob/master/Reachability/Reachability.swift

Comment: Sorry it was type error! thanks