# cannot invoke initializer for type 'Reachability' with no argument

Tags: ios, swift, reachability

I want to use the `ReachabilitySwift` class in my application. I added the dependency in my podFile and I get the code from [github](https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift).

I got this error:

**cannot invoke initializer for type 'Reachability' with no argument" on this line**

My code:

`let reachability = Reachability()!`

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the answer in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27310465/detecting-network-connectivity-changes-using-reachability-nsnotification-and-ne) and also this [one](https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift/issues/114), my project is running perfectly and my problem is solved.

By doing this: `var reachability: Reachability!` I can check the network reachability without using any host for the check.

Answer (score 1):

```
let reachability = Reachability(hostname: "http://whatYouWantToCheck.com")
```

or try a pod update

example from github

```
let reachability = Reachability()!

reachability.whenReachable = { reachability in
    // this is called on a background thread, but UI updates must
    // be on the main thread, like this:
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        if reachability.isReachableViaWiFi() {
            print("Reachable via WiFi")
        } else {
            print("Reachable via Cellular")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but is the reachability test made for network (in general) or for a specific link?

Comment: in the old ver. you had to use this func reachabilityForInternetConnection() but in the new one you can just use Reachability() try and update your lib it might not be up to date

Comment: I updated it but I have the same problem. Can you give me please a correct example from what I can check if the network is available or not (without using a hostname)?

Comment: I use the same code, but the build failed because of the error given in my question